# "Next Privilege" bar hard to read

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

Please check image below, this is the current view on the privileges page.
[image]

I've added one darker background color to the `<div class="meter">` resulting in this:
[image]

Would it be an option to update the background color for the "meter" class? It's much better to read with one color darker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have darkened the bar's background color some. the change will go out after the next production build.

Comment: Thanks. Your change is live.